# Start a System Timer once ASP.NET solution is hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, timer

I created an MVC ASP.NET Standard (Not .NET Core) solution and added a  `System.Timers.Timer` to it.
I started the timer in `Global.asax.cs` before the registration of the services.

Once hosted, the timer does not start until a client calls the website even though i am enabling timer in the `Application_Start` where a function will initiate and hook the timer as the following:

```
// Create a timer with a two second interval.
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(intervalInMiliseconds);
// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
aTimer.AutoReset = true;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

My question is, where should i initiate the timer if i want it to start regardless if there were connected users or not? Can i do this with ASP.NET Standard or should i use .NET Core?

My Scenario is that, i will created a Windows Service that host a SignalR hub and will periodically send a message to all connected users. I would like to do the same with IIS.

Comment: If your application did auto-start without the need for a client request, would that do the trick? [IIS Auto-Start](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/)

Comment: @OguzOzgul, interesting, i will try it and update you.

Comment: @OguzOzgul, i tried that setting but unfortunately, the project is still not starting automatically when i start the website hosted on IIS

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn more about IIS application pools/worker process settings in order to know why you should stick to a Windows service app, not IIS. Some facts can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a

Comment: I think you need to enable application initalization and app pool always running. Since web deployment tool won't recycle app pool by default. You also have to use web deploy to recycle the applicationpool. Then you will see the timer triggered after publishing.https://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/operations-on-application-pools-as-admin-and-non-admin

Comment: @JokiesDing, this post is from 2010. Is this approach still valid and recommended?

Comment: web deploy is still in use for IIS deployment. So it should be still valid.